# Biding their time to reveal their hidden depths

Tags: idioms

Is there a phrase for what a person is or is doing who is underrated by people but then shows themselves to contain hidden depths? Not quite a diamond in the rough. Sort of like dark horse. Hmm? Not sinister hidden depths. Like when my intellectually disabled daughter surprises all who underestimate her  by blurting out an insightful comment or clever joke.

Comment: "Silent waters run deep."

Comment: @Mitch - "Still waters run deep" is more idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks oh, yes, that's it. Mine was misremembered.

Comment: Are you worried that 'dark horse' has negative undertones? 'Though many favoured the bigger teams to win the competition, the local team was a dark horse, and surprised everyone with their dazzling performances.' [[theidioms.com](https://www.theidioms.com/dark-horse/)]

Comment: Not an answer, but I was wondering whether it is more accurate to consider your daughter to have simply a different pace rather than being "intellectually disabled, namely slower but not incapable?

Comment: She's not one to hide her light under a bushel.

Answer (score 1):

*Showing your true colours* has a similar meaning.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your answer could be improved by providing references. Please see [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

[**Feigning weakness**](https://tht.fangraphs.com/trade-strategy-feigning-weakness/) is an ancient strategy for deceiving your enemies.

This can also be called [**holding out on someone**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hold-out-on-sb).

> After she sunk a three cushion bank shot like a pro, he smiled and said, "You've been holding out on me."

There's also:

[**Holding one's cards close to their chest**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+cards+close+to+chest) which is similar to your request. It means keeping ones tactics, plans or intentions secret until you're willing to reveal them.

Moreover, there is the notion of [**hustling**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hustling) which is a term that originated in billiards. A hustler is a good player who usually hides their skill to get lesser players to play them for higher stakes.

But, to be honest, I'd typically just go for the phrase you used to ask your question.

Your daughter is just *biding her time* or *waiting for her moment.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if any of these are quite what you are getting at, but I can definitely think of some related concepts.

For example, in the case that this hidden ability (or whatever it may be) is being discussed or revealed for the first time to the audience, phrases like:

- "[natural-born](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/natural-born)" (adj.) or its variant "(a) born natural" (n.);
- having or possessing a "[hidden talent](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/amp/english/hidden-talent)" or a "gift";
- and in any competitive context, I would venture so far as to include "[sand-bagger](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sandbagger)," or even "[ringer](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ringer)," etc.
  but those generally have far more negative connotations than what you seem to be getting at -- usually as though the "hiding" was done intentionally.

But yeah if "diamond in the rough" isn't it, I doubt any of those are. Thought I'd chip in my two cents anyway, just in case!

Comment: Please add the relevant excerpts from the links to your answer. This prevents users from having to site-hop in order to get the full benefit. Links may also change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If the person is biding their time, looking for an opportune moment to contribute, and that is what you'd like to emphasize, perhaps:

**waiting in the wings**

> Also in figurative phr. waiting in the wings and variants, ready to
> act or make an appearance; (for the moment) taking no part in the
> action. OED